# RapidJson Writer: Not handling properly German accent characters with UTF16 encoding

Tags: c++, json

I need to create json Unicode text for a string value which includes German accent character: Prüfung

I implemented this code:

```
using namespace rapidjson;
typedef GenericDocument<UTF16<> > WDocument;
typedef GenericStringBuffer<UTF16<> > StringBufferW;

StringBufferW sb;
Writer<StringBufferW, UTF16<>> writerUTF16(sb); 

std::wstring name = L"Prüfung";

writerUTF16.StartObject();
{
    writerUTF16.String(L"name");
    writerUTF16.String(name.c_str(), static_cast<SizeType>(name.length()));
}
writerUTF16.EndObject();

std::wstring jsonText = sb.GetString();
```

Which is not working, the output of jsonText is: {"name":"Prￃﾼfung"}

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the source string is encoded the way you think it is? The string gets whatever the source file encoding is. If this is on Windows, the source file is probably not UTF. Try `\xfc` or `\X00FC` instead of `ü`.

Comment: The source string didn't resolve from a source file, it is simply a memory string: std::wstring name = L"Prüfung";

Comment: The result looks like UTF8, it's probably working. To display the text in Windows you have to convert back to UTF16. There is a lot of details missing in your question, I can't say much else.

Comment: @user2906743 if the string is written in source code, the encoding of the source code file comes into play. That's why I suggested trying the unambiguous hex encoded literal character escape code within the string.

Comment: That was just a simply code example to the real code where I receive the real complex text over TCP/IP packets so I cannot use the unambiguous hex encoded.  converting back to UTF16 "Fixed" the issue but I have not found any evidence that sb.GetString(); returns the text in UTF-8 encoding... Any help here is appreciated... Additionally, maybe I need to prefix the stream buffer with a mark this it UTF16 encoding with the hope GetString() will do the proper encoding ? How do I do that is this is the right approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at rapidjson Writer source code it is defined as:

```
template<typename OutputStream, typename SourceEncoding = UTF8<>, typename TargetEncoding = UTF8<>, typename StackAllocator = CrtAllocator, unsigned writeFlags = kWriteDefaultFlags>
class Writer
```

In your writer definition you only set UTF16 as SourceEncoding  but leave the default to TargetEncoding that is UTF8.

Please consider to change:

```
Writer<StringBufferW, UTF16<>> writerUTF16(sb);
```

with

```
Writer<StringBufferW, UTF16<>, UTF16<>> writerUTF16(sb);
```